# # character in url of jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Why is it that when I visit my jQuery mobile page, lets say page.php it shows up fine, but when I visit the same page page.php#someDetailsHere it just shows a white page?
And how can I fix this?

I use a third party app that redirects to my webpage with the `#` added to the url..

Comment: strangely, it shows up if I remove
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
from my header... but then the page is style-less

Comment: have you checked if the page is displayed but hidden by query because you haven't navigated to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I stepped through your page to see what was going on.

Your grief is caused by jQuery Mobile. When the page loads, it detects this as an "page change", and because jQuery Mobile uses the hash (`#`) to emulate the back-button for AJAX requests, it also has some special handling for pages that it sees are loaded with a hash.

The bottom line is that it sees a page load, decides it should "reject" it, and prevents anything further from happening.

My guess is that the jQuery Mobile team didn't expect anyone to load a mobile page with a hash on init, since the code seems to assume that the first load of the page will not have one.

To follow this yourself, set a breakpoint in the function `isEmbeddedPage` in `jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css`.

A possible solution would be to somehow prevent the jQuery Mobile code from running when the page initially loads. This might break other stuff that jQuery Mobile provides, though.

Comment: thanks for you answer. i think i'll try to fint another solution. the pain is caused by the ios app picupapp, which is designed to make fileupload present in the mobile safari. strangely enogh, not in cooperation with jquery mobile

Comment: I was thrown by this. The fact that jQM doesn't fire any custom events (despite building everything) and rests on a loading/rendering state strikes me as a bug. Notice you can reproduce this on their own [demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/#erg) (as of writing).

Should this be filed as a bug? Methinks yes.

Answer (score 1):

As  says It turns out jQM parses hashes for its own purposes and just freezes if it can't make sense of them on load (unnecessarily aggressive behaviour if you ask me, they should at least fire a custom event — although there is a [high priority issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4119) reported for it on GitHub).

One solution is to disable jQM's hash processing: before DOM ready, execute the following:

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

Note this will necessarily break any functional reliance on jQM's history polyfill on browsers that don't support history pushState (IE etc).